# Can the set of uneven number be written as the intersection of two sets?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $U = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} | n \equiv 1 (2) \}$.
My question is: Can we find two proper subsets $M,N$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $M \neq N$ and $M,N$ are not equal to  $U$ and $U = M \cap N$? It feels, that this is not the case, but how does one prove that?

Comment: I assume you don't want $M$ or $N$ to be equal to $U$? There are trivial solutions $M = \mathbb{N} \backslash \{2\}$ and $N = U$.

Comment: Yes, they should not be equal to $U$. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Even still, $M = U \cup \{2\}$ and $N = U \cup \{4\}$ are solutions.

Comment: Sorry I read uneven as even!

Comment: The usual English term for integers that are not even is "odd".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M=U\cup\{4\}$ and $N=U\cup \{6\}$. Neither are $U$ and $M\cap N=U$.

Answer (score 2):

Any proper subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that the complement of $S$ has cardinality greater than or equal to $2$ can be written in the form you want. Suppose that $\mathbb{N} \backslash S \supseteq \{a,b\}$ then
$$ S = (S \cup \{a\}) \cap (S \cup \{b\}). $$
It's easy to see that any set whose compliment contains fewer than $2$ elements can not be written in the form you want. This gives a complete description of sets that can be written in this form.